# Stuck in linux boot menu and cannot install Win

Tags: system-installation

After installing Ubuntu on my laptop and even change Hard Drive (for another reason) I cannot boot from Windows installer anymore and just showing box when system turn on which have two menus: boot: Ubuntu and app menu: [empty]. And then just nothing happen.

[boot menu 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZByP.jpg)

[boot menu 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcUzj.jpg)

Comment: Providing a picture of what you're trying to describe may have helped (I don't understand what you mean by two menus and a box...) but also would have providing all details (are you talking about Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Desktop, or something else? and which release etc)

Comment: Ubuntu Descktop. Simply I can not boot form Windows installation Disc.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.    (windows is not Ubuntu or *flavor* of Ubuntu, so why ask here?)

Comment: Maybe the GRUB bootloader is not detecting windows, that's why you are booted directly to ubuntu.

Comment: @guiverc Because It's problem after installing Ubuntu and I even cannot load Ubuntu installer on new HDD

Comment: @ArjunKShibu I cannot access to BIOS settings by checking any keyboard keys

Comment: @guiverc https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZByP.jpg and https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcUzj.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You must be enabled USB Booting on your BIOS settings. You can try F1 - F12 buttons at startup. Then a window should appear that showing all drives. You can install Windows by choosing your drive.

Comment: I check every single keys on keyboard but nothing happen and not going to BIOS setting

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZByP.jpg and https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcUzj.jpg

Comment: New hard drive and just this menu loading. Not loading any boot loader not enter BIOS Settings check every keys...